# Postgresql and rails with act-as-taggable-on error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

I have this statement to choose a given number of random records from the database that match certain set of tags. I am using `act-as-taggable-on` gem for tagging.

```
 questions=Question.select('questions.*,RANDOM()').tagged_with(tags,:any=>true).order("RANDOM()").limit(test.no_of_questions)
```

I am using postgresql and I get the following error.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DISTINCT"
LINE 1: SELECT  questions.*,RANDOM(), DISTINCT questions.* FROM "que...
                                      ^
: SELECT  questions.*,RANDOM(), DISTINCT questions.* FROM "questions" JOIN taggings quest_taggings_14e6dd0  ON quest_taggings_14e6dd0.taggable_id = "questions".id AND quest_taggings_14e6dd0.taggable_type = 'Question' WHERE (quest_taggings_14e6dd0.tag_id = 1) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3
```

I am not sure what to do because I think the Distinct part is inserted by the tagging gem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it along these lines

```
Question.tagged_with(tags,:any=>"true").order("RANDOM()").limit(limit_number)
```

### update

As shown here http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2010-10/msg00004.php

You need to put the DISTINCT and the ORDER BY in separate query levels.

Apparently, the above Query would work with other DB but not Postgresql

Comment: I get following error for that. 
     PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ... 1 OR quest_taggings_3b7ddc8.tag_id = 2) ORDER BY RANDOM() L...
                                                              ^
        : SELECT  DISTINCT questions.* FROM "questions" JOIN taggings quest_taggings_3b7ddc8  ON quest_taggings_3b7ddc8.taggable_id = "questions".id AND quest_taggings_3b7ddc8.taggable_type = 'Question' WHERE (quest_taggings_3b7ddc8.tag_id = 1 OR quest_taggings_3b7ddc8.tag_id = 2) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind Ive found the solution.

I did this:

```
questions=Question.tagged_with(tags,:any=>true)
  questions=questions.select('questions.*,RANDOM()').order("RANDOM()").limit(test.no_of_questions)
```

This way the `questions.*` wasnt included twice in the select statement.